# how can i test my xpath has identified right element on android/iOS native application

Tags: android, ios, testing, xpath, appium

Android User Name field Details:
content-desc: 
type: android.widget.EditText
text: Username
index: 0
enabled: true
location: {30, 293}
size: {480, 60}
checkable: false
checked: false
focusable: true
clickable: true
long-clickable: true
package: com.senrysa.parkingplace
password: false
resource-id: com.senrysa.parkingplace:id/LoginUserName
scrollable: false
selected: false
xpath: //android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.ScrollView[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[2]/android.widget.EditText[1]

I have created partial xpath with attribute text ... i.e.
xpath = "//android.widget.EditText[@text='Username']")

but it has not worked.

how can i test my xpath has identified right element on android/iOS native application?

Comment: I have checked through path tester...it is working. but @AndroidFindBy(xpath = ("//android.widget.EditText[@text='Username']")) has not worked :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try to increase the implicit wait time for your WebDriver so it doesn't error out before the element is visible.

Please share your code snippet and error stack for precise solutuion.

Answer (score 0):

When you just want to confirm xpath for particular element, 
You should try below action:

- click if button/link
- sendKeys if inputfield
- check/un-check if checkbox

I guess, this would be the simplest way to verify @Tanmay

Comment: @TanmayRay - Please delete your below answer, Instead pls do comments when you want to communicate with someone in regards with their answers. I will respond you there in comments.

Answer (score 0):

@Narendra

I have checked through XPath Tester... and it worked properly .

but

when we use 
@AndroidFindBy(xpath = ("//android.widget.EditText[@text='Username']")) has not worked

Is *@AndroidFindBy* identified by this xpath where as absolute xpath has worked properly.